# Partial AJAX render while still loading

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im using Ruby on Rails and jQuery.

Just wondering if you guys know a way to request an array with jQuery and then render each member of the array to the HTML body that have completed loading while continuing to load the others.

For example.

If I use jQuery to request a script that returns me 30 members in an JSON array. Normally you wont get access to that array until the WHOLE array is completely loaded. But what if array member 1,2 and 3 are completed. Is there a way I can use those members while members 4-30 continue to load? Is that possible? Some sort of progressive rendering? loading?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but you could request them one at a time in a loop:

```
function getNext(num) {
    $.getJSON('/path', 'num=' + num).done(function () {
        getNext(num + 1);
    });
}
```

When you get to the last one, send a 404 and `.done` won't be called.

Comment: Yeah I am really concentrating on minimising the load time. Making it really snappy. It would just be better to load the whole array and wait then to conduct 30 separate requests.